# No audio in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with VirtualBox 5.0.20

Tags: 16.04, sound, virtualbox, lubuntu

I have been breaking my head on this for a day and a half now.

I am running VirtualBox 5.0.20 r106931 in Windows 8.1.  My Guest system is Lubuntu 16.04 LTS, and I have successfully installed the VirtualBox Guest Additions.  Afer all this,  I cannot hear any audio when running either a video in Firefox, or an mp3 file in Audacious on my Guest Lubuntu system.

I have tried all three Audio settings: SoundBlaster 16, ICH AC97, and Intel HD Audio.  I have checked all of the sound levels that I can find, and none of them is set to mute.

When I am running Audacious, the app shows that sound is being played and when I run a video in Firefox, the PulseAudioVolumeControl likewise shows that sound is being played [through something called the CubebUtils Audio Stream].

Any suggestions gratefully received.

Comment: Hmmmm, it sounds to me that you have not enabled the audio interface in the Devices menu when the VB is running. You're sure it is enabled?

Comment: No audio interface is shown in the Devices menu.  The choices are Optical Drives, Network, USB, Webcams, Shared Folders, Shared Clipboard, Drag and Drop, and Insert Guest Additions CD Image. I've looked at each of these, and in no place does an Audio Interface show up.

Comment: Just saw something.  Is the 16.04 Lubuntu release only for amd-based machines??

Comment: Further reading of documentation suggests that it doesn't matter which processor [Intel/AMD] is on the machine

Comment: I think that I may have figured this out.  When I was installing lubuntu, I originally chose to install a "Minimum Virtual Server".  Evidently this minimal version did not have something that was needed to play sound through my host machine, and though I tried very hard to figure out what was missing, I could never do so.

Comment: I just created a new virtual machine and installed an "OEM master" version of Lubuntu.  With this version, audio seems to work just fine.

I am now going to go back and try a third Lubuntu option: "Minimal System" and see how that works.

If anybody has any quick suggestions as to what might have been missing in the "Minimal Virtual Server" version, I would appreciate it.

Comment: The "Minimum System" choice also enabled sound.  As I was going through this installation, I only chose LAMP, Remote SSH Handler, and Standard Utilities.  These choices DID allow me to play audio through my host machine.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention the Host Sound Driver. In my windows 10 Family, I have `Windows Direct Sound` combined with `Intel HD`. You can give a try. Also in Ubuntu 16.04, you might need to adjust the sound settings as well. See screen shots attached.

[image]
[image]